# Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be one-to-one and differentiable with $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Show $f^{-1}$ is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function

This is exercise 5.2.12 from *Understanding Analysis* 2nd ed.

If $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is one-to-one , then there exists an inverse function $f^{-1}$ defined on the range of $f$ given by $f^{-1}(y) = x$ where $y=f(x)$. I previously went through the proof that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f^{-1}$ is continuous on its domain.

Assume that $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ with $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Show $f^{-1}$ is differentiable with $$(f^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$$ where $y=f(x)$.

**My work so far**: Let $d = f(c)$ for an arbitrary $c \in [a,b]$. We have
$$(f^{-1})'(d) = lim_{y \rightarrow d} \frac{f^{-1}(y) - f^{-1}(d)}{y-d}.$$

We can substitute in $f(x)$ for $y$ and $f(c)$ for $d$ to give
$$(f^{-1})'(d) =  (f^{-1})'(f(c))= lim_{f(x) \rightarrow f(c)} \frac{x - c}{f(x)-f(c)}.$$

It is at this point that I am stuck. All I need to do is show I can replace $f(x) \rightarrow f(c)$ with $x \rightarrow c$ in the limit. If I can do that, then (using the algebraic rules for limits) I would have
$$lim_{x \rightarrow c} \frac{x - c}{f(x)-f(c)} = \frac{lim_{x \rightarrow c} 1}{lim_{x \rightarrow c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}} = \frac{1}{f'(c)}.$$

Just having trouble justifying the replacement of $f(x) \rightarrow f(c)$ with $x \rightarrow c$.

Comment: You can do the exchange because f is ONE-ONE so f(x) can tend to f(c) iff x tends to c.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Yeah, so I'm seeing that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are also strictly monotone. Still having trouble proving the fact that $f(x) \rightarrow f(c)$ iff $x \rightarrow c$. Do I need to make an argument involving limits... like using the fact that (because they are continuous) $lim_{x \rightarrow c}f(x) =f(c)$ and $lim_{f(x) \rightarrow f(c)}f^{-1}(f(x)) =f^{-1}(f(c))$?

Comment: @pup2089 You will need to use sequences (at least formally). But yes, the argument will use critically the fact that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$c\in [a,b].$$  We need to show that $$\lim_{y\rightarrow f(c)}\frac{g(f(c))-g(y)}{f(c)-y}$$ exists. We can do this via the sequential characterization of limits.

Let $y_n\rightarrow f(c)$ any sequence in $f[a,b]$. Then we know for each n, there exists $x_n\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_n) = y_n$. So $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(c)$. Then $$
\lim_{y_n\rightarrow f(c)}\frac{g(f(c))-g(y_n)}{f(c)-y_n} 
= \lim_{f(x_n)\rightarrow f(c)}\frac{g(f(c))-g(y_n)}{f(c)-y_n} =
\lim_{f(x_n)\rightarrow f(c)}\frac{c-x_n}{f(c)-f(x_n)} .$$ Then since $f^{-1}$ continuous (previous exercise in Abbot) we know that  $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(c) \implies f^{-1}(f(x_n))\rightarrow f^{-1}(f(c)) \implies (x_n) \rightarrow c$.

Thus $$\lim_{f(x_n)\rightarrow f(c)}\frac{c-x_n}{f(c)-f(x_n)}
= \lim_{x_n\rightarrow c}\frac{c-x_n}{f(c)-f(x_n)} =^{\text{seq. char.}} \frac{1}{f'(c)}.$$

Since $f$ is differentiable at $c$ we know the limit exists. Hence $g$ differential at $f(c)$ and so $$g'(f(c)) = \frac{1}{f'(c)}.$$